# Creating Sonar "users" DB table automatically - how "crypted_password" field is calculated?

Tags: sonarqube

We're setting up Sonar "users" table automatically. For each user we have its password and we can generate a random salt so then we just need to generate a "crypted_password" field. My question is how this field is generated? I tried SHA-1 and combining password and a salt - so far couldn't come up with the same encrypted password.

Thanks!

Comment: May I suggest that you use the `/api/users/create` Webservice instead of direct DB inserts ? In the long term, this is probably more maintainable.

Comment: It may be more complex but let me check it

Comment: Yeap, I see it's just one curl: http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=231080601#WebServiceapiusers-CreateaUser. Nice, but won't work in our case as each user generates its own hash which later used to populate the DB so the automation doesn't know the real passwords - it only gets to see user password hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, given the salt and the password here's how it works:

```
MessageDigest sha1 = DigestUtils.getSha1Digest();
sha1.update(( "--" + salt + "--" + password + "--" ).getBytes());
return Hex.encodeHexString( sha1.digest());
```

Assuming default values for `REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY` (empty string)  and `REST_AUTH_DIGEST_STRETCHES` (1): [1](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar/blob/aeadc1f9129274949daaa57738c7c4550bdfbc7b/sonar-server/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/vendor/plugins/restful_authentication/lib/authentication/by_password.rb#L30), 
[2](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar/blob/aeadc1f9129274949daaa57738c7c4550bdfbc7b/sonar-server/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/vendor/plugins/restful_authentication/lib/authentication.rb#L30).